# Where can I find serpent emblems?

Tags: resident-evil-6

There are 80 emblems for the Heirlooms achievement. What do they look like and where can I find them? Are there any indicators when I'm close to one? Are they used for anything?

[image: Heirlooms]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, there does not appear to be any indicators when you are nearby one - this is part of the challenge.

Collecting them enables you to unlock "files and figures" which can be viewed from the main menu in Special Features > Collections.

[There is a guide here](http://www.gamesradar.com/resident-evil-6-serpent-emblem-locations-guide/) as to the locations, this appears to be a complete guide to all 80 emblems with images/videos to help.

And to answer your final query, see below for what one looks like. In order to "collect" an emblem you need to destroy it, this can be done by shooting it, or you can save some ammo by using a knife attack on the closer ones.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[Games Radar](http://www.gamesradar.com/resident-evil-6-serpent-emblem-locations-guide/) has an entire guide with videos and pictures on where they all are. Basically there are four emblems to be found in each chapter of the four campaigns. Below I am listing four from the first chapter. If anyone wants to post the entire list here to avoid link rot, I am community wiking this post.

**Leon's Campaign - Chapter 1**

1. **Emblem 1**: Once you regain control after meeting Liz’s father, don’t proceed through the exit door in front of you. Instead, go left around the computer table and check the open storage closet.
2. **Emblem 2**: After escaping the horde in the hallway, you’ll have to make your way through a series of offices to find the campus keycard. In the third office there are three desks grouped together. Search the drawers to find a emblem.
3. **Emblem 3**: Soon after the segment in which the lights go out, you’ll open a door that leads back to the tracks. Drop down and turn right. There’s an emblem just underneath the train car.
4. **Emblem 4**: Just after the segment in which Helena gets tossed over to the opposite fire escape to open a door, you’ll find yourself inside a small bar. Walk past the counter and turn left. The emblem is under the bulletin board.